# How to fix a 3xx redirect using .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect from my domain name to a custom index page and am using this rewrite rule for it

```
# HTID:1827272: DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag log_errors off
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE HTID:1827272:
IndexIgnore *
Options -Indexes

#Alternate default index pages
ErrorDocument 404 /error/theme/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error500.php
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 4 month"

  # CSS

    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 5 month"


  # Data interchange

    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"


  # Favicon (cannot be renamed!) and cursor images

    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon              "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 5 year"

  # HTML

    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"


  # JavaScript

    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"


  # Manifest files

    ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"


  # Media files

    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/bmp                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"


  # Web fonts

    # Embedded OpenType (EOT)
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/eot                              "access plus 1 year"

    # OpenType
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 year"

    # TrueType
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 year"

    # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 1.0
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 year"
    # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 2.0
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 year"


  # Other

    ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy            "access plus 1 week"
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml
</IfModule>
 # to prevent ifame the code bellow

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>


 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gamehup.000webhostapp.com [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.gamehup.000webhostapp.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://gamehup.com/browser-games/index [L,R=301,NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]


RewriteBase /
#only for the root directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
#if the uri is not already index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/browser-games/index [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /browser-games/index    [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.gamehup\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://gamehup.com/browser-games/index [R=301,NC,L]
```

The only problem is am using Cloudflare to always use https that why it redirects first from 
`http://gamehup.com to https://gamehup.com then to http://gamehup.com/browser-games/index then to https://gamehup.com/browser-games/index`

And that lots of redirects, how can I make it only one?

```
from http://gamehup.com to https://gamehup.com/browser-games/index
```

This is all the htaccess code am using.

Comment: can you show the full htaccess?

Comment: i added al the htaccess file see above